# operator<< для STL-контейнеров

Tags: stl, qt, c++

В Qt имеется перегруженный оператор << для разных контейнеров: QVector, QList и т.д. Например, можно написать так:

```
QVector<QString> vec;
vec << QString("text1") << QString ("text2");
```

Для STL-контейнеров также можно нечто подобное реализовать. К примеру, я такой написал код для std::vector

```
template <class T, class E> std::vector<T>& operator<< (std::vector<T>& vec, const E& elem) {
    vec.push_back (elem);
    return vec;
}
```

Можно писать так:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec << 54234 << 998;
```

Или даже так:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec << std::string ("word 1") << "word 2";
```

Удобство подобной штуки очевидно. Как Вы думаете, какие могут быть в этом подходе подводные камни? (Я  имею в виду общую идею, а не мой конкретный код, хотя если найдете в нем ошибки или способ его улучшить, буду очень благодарен)

Comment: При беглом просмотре кода все будут считать, что это вывод в файл (а потом искать его в коде и ругаться).

Но, не стоит обращать на мой комментарий серьезного внимания, т.к. я принципиальный противник переопределения операций.

Comment: 1. В программах с Qt такие штуки встречаются часто и пока никто не жаловался.

2. Я думаю, тут дело глубже - в принципиальном неприятии Вами ООП. )))) А зря, батенька.

Comment: ООП в смысле Объектно Ориентированное **Проектирование** для ряда задач жизненно необходимо (и тут я его приветствую).

А переопределение операций и безудержное применение иерархии классов запутывают программы.

Comment: переопределение >> и << будет нормально только для стека и очереди. А для вектора оно выглядит странно. Там добавлять как то принято не  только в конец.
Хотя если начали извращаться, так нужно по полной! а почему бы для вектора не сделать модификаторы, что бы можно было делать вставку в середину. Где то так

    vec << 1 << 2 << 3 << setpos(1) << 0 << setpos(vec:end) << 4;
    std::cout << vec;

и должно в результате получиться что то вида
[1,0,2,3,4]

Как академическая задача, для изучения - отлична. Для практических задач - плохо.

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня создается впечатление, что push_back - наиболее часто используемый модифицирующий метод у векторов. Почему бы не сделать operator<< как удобную альтернативу для него?

Answer (score 17):

*Синтаксис удобный, но подводные камни все-таки есть.*

- Рассмотрим следующий код. Понятно, что в момент `(1)` в контейнере будут храниться 3 строчки, и это всех устраивает.

  ```
  QVector<QString> v; 
  v.append("Морж1");
  v.append("Морж2");
  v.append("Морж3");
  // (1)
  ```
- Дальше программист Иван замечает, что этот код можно упростить c помощью крутого синтаксиса:

  ```
  QVector<QString> v = QVector<QString>() << "Морж1" << "Морж2" << "Морж3";

                     ^
  ```
- После этого приходит тимлид Илларион и видит, что в месте, отмеченном галочкой, выполняется ненужное копирование объекта *(предположим, что Илларион не очень в курсе про [**copy-on-write**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/implicit-sharing.html)).*
- Зато Илларион в курсе про использование константных ссылок в похожих случаях - он знает, что по стандарту (`[C++ Standard] - 10.4.10 Temporary Objects`), если константная ссылка инициализируется временной переменной, то **время жизни этой переменной становится равным времени жизни ссылки.**
- Опираясь на свое знание стандарта, самоуверенный Илларион достаточно часто пишет такой код, и у него все прекрасно работает:

  ```
  const QVector<QString>& ref = QVector<QString>(3, "Морж");
  Q_ASSERT(ref.size() == 3);
  ```
- И по этой же причине он не особо задумывается, когда правит код Ивана на следующий и нажимает кнопочку `commit`:

  ```
  const QVector<QString>& v = QVector<QString>() << "Морж1" << "Морж2" << "Морж3";
  ```
- ### Бабах!

---

- Иллариону приходит гневное письмо от системы `Continuous Integration` о том, что его коммит сломал несколько тестов. *А ему еще повезло, что этот код был ими покрыт!*
- А дело тут вот в чем *(это реализация `operator<<` для `QVector`):*

  ```
  inline QVector<T>& operator<<(const T &t)
  {
      append(t);
      return *this;
  }
  ```
- Как можно заметить, последняя из операций (`<<`) возвращает ссылку (`QVector<T>&`) на созданную чуть раньше временную переменную `QVector<QString>`. Естественно, что никто в таком случае не будет продлевать время жизни этой переменной - последняя операция `<<` при синтаксическом разборе не имеет *(и не нуждается в)* информации о том, где и как была эта переменная была создана.
- *Технически говоря, это `rvalue`, из которой путем неявного преобразования мы получили `lvalue`.*
- Если подытожить, то `const QVector<QString>& v` - [**висячая ссылка,**](http://code.rkevin.com/2010/07/c-pitfall-beware-of-dangling-references/) соответствующий ей объект уже уничтожен, а Илларион мог бы лишиться премии, если бы не писал тесты. Вот такая вот история.

Comment: Если кому не по душе такой стиль повествования, то извините, настроение просто соответствующее :)

Comment: В общем. мораль: не надо лишний раз выпендриваться.

Comment: Стиль - что надо. Я сам так иногда на работе инструкции пишу для сотрудников, от чего иногда получаю по шее.

Comment: Здорово написано.

Comment: This is madness...